# Python script doesn't open the jar file and deletes the first comments in config.yml, plugin.yml and bungee.yml, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-zipfile

my python script is supposed to have the task to automatically open a .jar file in the directory when running (without asking which one, because there will always be only one).

The jar file can be opened as an archive, and is supposed to look for 3 files in it: plugin.yml, bungee.yml and config.yml. If there is one or more of these files, it should simply delete the first comment with # of these files and then it must save the new file with the same name as the original at the end with "_drog".

In the 3 files, it will read the contents line by line and delete the first line it finds that has a # in it.

If there is no line with # in it, the script will not delete anything.

That's the current script

the script should select any jar file that is in the directory

```
import zipfile
import os

# function to remove the first comment starting with '#'.
def remove_first_comment(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        comment_removed = False
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip().startswith("#") and not comment_removed:
                comment_removed = True
                continue
            file.write(line)

# Find the JAR file in the current directory
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
jar_file_path = None

for file in os.listdir(current_dir):
    if file.endswith(".jar"):
        jar_file_path = os.path.join(current_dir, file)
        break

if not jar_file_path:
    print("No JAR file found.")
    exit()

# path to the extracted directory
extracted_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "extracted_temp")

# Extract the JAR file
with zipfile.ZipFile(jar_file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(extracted_path)

# path to the files inside the extracted directory
plugin_yml_path = os.path.join(extracted_path, "plugin.yml")
bungee_yml_path = os.path.join(extracted_path, "bungee.yml")
config_yml_path = os.path.join(extracted_path, "config.yml")

# check and remove the first comment from the files, if any
if os.path.exists(plugin_yml_path):
    remove_first_comment(plugin_yml_path)
if os.path.exists(bungee_yml_path):
    remove_first_comment(bungee_yml_path)
if os.path.exists(config_yml_path):
    remove_first_comment(config_yml_path)

# replace the original JAR file with the modified file
output_jar_path = os.path.join(current_dir, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(jar_file_path))[0] + "_mc-forums.jar")
with zipfile.ZipFile(output_jar_path, 'w') as zip_ref:
    for root, _, files in os.walk(extracted_path):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            arcname = os.path.relpath(file_path, extracted_path)
            zip_ref.write(file_path, arcname)

# delete the extracted directory
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(extracted_path, topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
    for dir in dirs:
        os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, dir))
os.rmdir(extracted_path)

# Replace the original JAR file with the modified one
os.remove(jar_file_path)
os.rename(output_jar_path, jar_file_path)

print("done")
```

I tried to run the script several times, but it always created a folder called "extracted_temp" that contained the files extracted from the JAR file (unchanged).

Filename: testing.jar

I expected the script to then create a new jar file named testing_drog.jar and remove the first comments from plugin.yml, bungee.yml and config.yml there.

Comment: After assigning to `plugin_yml_path`, add a line to print the content of the variable and check if it is the expected and right path (probably not).